# Owl-carousel только на мобилках

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

Подскажите, есть какое-либо решение, чтобы отключать owl-carousel на больших разрешениях, и включать только на мобилках ?

Comment: Сделай инициализацию каруселя только тогда когда разрешение экрана меньше определенного `$(window).width() < x`.

Comment: Вот и хорошо, но это уже не надо в вопросе писать

Answer (score 1):

Написал скрипт, отлично работает. Может кому пригодится.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $(window).on('resize', function(){
      if($(window).width() <= 767) {
      $('.doc-block').addClass('owl-carousel');
      }
       else {
      $('.doc-block').removeClass('owl-carousel');
      }
      }).trigger('resize');
    });
```

Comment: Только еще нужно проверку сделать и в `$(document).ready()`, что бы при открытии сразу на телефоне оно то же работало.

Comment: ну document это понятно. сейчас добавлю. Не могу понять, почему при ресайзе окна не работает ? trigger же стоит :( Работает только если сразу на мобилках открывать

Answer (score 0):

Обычно проверку на мобильник выполняют всё-таки в php или ином языке, на стороне сервера при формировании страницы. Вряд-ли блок, подготовленный для карусели, имеет такие же параметры, как и без карусели. Поэтому замена класса - сложный путь - как в сказке "и дудочку, и кувшинчик", ну или "на ёлку влезть и на ... сесть".

Проще сразу проверить тип устройства и интегрировать в готовую страницу уже специализированный код. Будет и проще, и лучше, и меньше. В *WordPress*, например, есть специализированная функция [wp_is_mobile()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_is_mobile). По ссылке можно посмотреть, что она проверяет и сделать свою по необходимости.

Проверка размеров экрана устройства также не годится. Современные смартфоны имеют разрешение практически не уступающее десктопам. Но десктопный вариант страницы на них неудобочитаем.